# How to Vectorize Dependent For-Loops in Matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, profiling, vectorization, nested-loops

I was wondering if anyone could help me to vectorize this part of my code. Here, bin_pdf is binomial coefficient function. pb and pd are scalar parameters. Thank You!

```
    for t=0:min(T,r)
        for n=0:r-t
            pp = (bin_pdf(n,pb,r-t) * bin_pdf(t,pd,min(T,r)));
            pt = pt + t/r * pp;
            pn = pn + n/r * pp;
            pc = pc + (r-t-n)/r * pp;
        end
    end
```

where

```
function p = bin_pdf(x,rho,n) 
if (x > n) || (n < 0) 
    p = 0; 
else 
    p = Choosenk(n,x) * rho^x * (1-rho)^(n-x); 
end
```

and

```
function C=Choosenk(n,k) 
if k>n/2 
    k=n-k; 
end; 
C=1; 
for i=0:k-1 
     C=C*(n-i)/(k-i); 
end 
end
```

Comment: What is the shape of pp, pt, pn, and pc?  Are they scalars, vectors, or arrays?  And which of the quantities is your output when your are finished with the double loop?

Comment: @chipaudette I add the contents of bin_pdf in below. pp, pt, pn, and pc are scalar. I need the final results of them after all iterations.

Comment: Can't you just use [`binopdf`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/binopdf.html)?

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank you!!! that's a very good idea! I can get rid of inside loop, i.e. "for n=0:r-t" by binopdf? Could you give any suggestion that I can remove the other one too, i.e. "for t=0:min(T,r)". The reason is that this nested loop is also inside of other loops. And it runs a lot of times. So I am trying to get rid of that.

Comment: @SoheilHosseini I'm not sure how to do that. You should post code that can be run by just pasting it in the command window, so we can try. That is, include a minimal example with all input variables defined, that produces the desired output

Answer (score 0):

This is the vectorized Choosenk. if you dont call it somewhere else you could integrate it into the bin_pdf.

```
function C=Choosenk(n,k) 
if k>n/2 
    k=n-k; 
end; 
C=prod((n-k+1:n)./(1:k));
end
```

Comment: i can give it a try. could you please provide some data examples in your question?

Comment: there are no specific numbers for them. You can choose whatever you want for them. Thanks!